# update the version in package.json without clean git working directory (without a task runner like Gulp)

Tags: npm

When running a: `npm version prepatch` I get the error: "Git working directory not clean." And then a list of files that aren't committed yet.

However, I'd like to do this prerelease to test some stuff locally using a private npm registry. Meaning that I don't have to commit the files just yet using Git.

Is it possible to update the version in package.json without clean git working directory?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

From the npm version documentation at https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version:

> If run in a git repo, it will also create a version commit and tag. This behavior is controlled by git-tag-version (see below), and can be disabled on the command line by running npm --no-git-tag-version version. It will fail if the working directory is not clean, unless the -f or --force flag is set.

I'm not 100% certain whether you just need --no-git-tag-version, or if you'll also need the --force flag.

Comment: You only need to specify `--no-git-tag-version` when doing `npm version` to avoid this error.

Answer (score 16):

The error is because you are in a git repository and there are uncommitted changes.
You can use `git stash`.

E.g.

```
git stash 
npm version patch 
git stash pop
```

This will reset your working directory temporarily (remove uncommitted changes). Then you can run `npm version {major|minor|patch}`. Afterwards, using `git stash pop` will re-apply your uncommitted changes to your working directory.

Tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/saving-changes/git-stash#stashing-your-work

Comment: You will have set the configuration for NPM like your email and username

Answer (score 4):

Try to commit first

```
git add . && git commit -am "new version"
```

and then

```
npm version patch
```